# Is there any way to handle websocket onmessage handler just like done method handlers attached to XHR deferred objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm currently doing this hack to handle the websocket's onmessage.

```
$scope.wsCon.onMessage = function(result) {
    $scope.wsCon.trigger(result.handler, result.data);
};
```

Problem here is that, onmessage is handling all the incoming requests through websocket.

But I need something like this:

```
$scope.wsCon.
    .send(data)
    .done(data, function (result) {
        // Deal with the result here
    })
    .fail(data, function() {
        // Show the error message
    })
    .complete(data, function() {
        // Do this always
    });
```

I know this is not achievable in websocket on single connection. But still, is there any way to produce effect something like the way jQuery does?

Comment: This looks more like angular than jquery

Comment: You just need a function that relates every answer to the request that triggered it. Then you can resolve your deferred with it.

Comment: Currently I'm doing the same thing right?

I'm sending the handler name in send function like this:
send({data:"", handler:"handlerName"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets are not request/response based, so since there is no response required when you send a message, what do you expect to happen to finish that promise? the socket flushing the buffer? :) If the browser fails to send the message because the socket is dead, you will get an "onerror" message.

If you need confirmation of the message, or awaiting a response, you need to implement it yourself.

Please take a look at this answer : [AngularJS and WebSockets beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299403/angularjs-and-websockets-beyond/26300758#26300758) About this [$connection service](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/blob/master/samples/TerminalServer/TerminalServer.Web/content/scripts/app.js) declared in this [WebSocket based AngularJS application](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-Terminal-Server)

Basically it is an example about creating a WebSocket service in AngularJS that can be used to request/response and publish/subscribe.

Basically you can listen for messages:

```
   $connection.listen(function (msg) { return msg.type == "CreatedTerminalEvent"; }, 
        function (msg) {
            addTerminal(msg);
            $scope.$$phase || $scope.$apply();
   });
```

Listen once (great for request/response):

```
$connection.listenOnce(function (data) {
    return data.correlationId && data.correlationId == crrId;
}).then(function (data) {
    $rootScope.addAlert({ msg: "Console " + data.terminalType + " created", type: "success" });
});
```

And send messages:

```
$connection.send({
    type: "TerminalInputRequest",
    input: cmd,
    terminalId: $scope.terminalId,
    correlationId: $connection.nextCorrelationId()
});
```